# One-liner to change a prototype method into a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The `String` object in Javascript has a method called `toLowerCase`. The problem with that method is that it requires that you already have a String object.

What if I wanted to turn that prototype method into a function that could be called on a String?

I know that I can do this:

```
var f = function (str) { return str.toLowerCase(); }
f("HI") // = "hi"
```

I want to avoid using the `function` keyword.

I thought that, since I can do this...

```
String.prototype.toLowerCase.call("HI") // = "hi"
```

...that I could then do this:

```
var f = String.prototype.toLowerCase.call
f("HI")
```

But this results in an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: f is not a function
```

Same goes for `apply` and `bind`.

I want the resulting function to be callable using `f("HI")`, so using `call` and `apply` aren't allowed.

Is there way to accomplish this without resorting to using `function`?

For those of you who will inevitably wonder why I won't use the `function` keyword, it's just curiosity to help me understand JavaScript better. I'm not trying to be fancy, or efficient, or anything. I'm not trying to optimize prematurely, etc., so please refrain from Knuth quotes.

Comment: "The problem with that method is that it requires that you already have a String object." - Same is true of any function that takes a parameter though. When stepping away from object-oriented programming, the first "invisible argument" to any instance function is a reference to the object itself. What you're trying to aim for is a function that has a `this` parameter, throws it away, and only uses the next argument. ...That *said*, you got my mind curious, so I'm about to post my answer.

Comment: Creating shortcuts: [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Creating_shortcuts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. Quite a mental puzzle you put together, and I wasn't sure there was any way to have the first argument be accepted how we want it.

```
var pointlessFunctionBindingForJavascriptHackers =
   Function.prototype.call.bind(String.prototype.toLowerCase)
```

Comment: Nice! Now I'm embarrassed by my answer. I'll have to pretend that the  motivation for mine is to avoid an ECMAScript feature not supported in older browsers, rather than because I simply didn't think of it. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Is it cheating to precreate an `demethodize` function?

```
function demethodize(meth) {
    return function () {
        return Function.prototype.call.apply(meth, arguments);
    }
}

var f = demethodize(String.prototype.toLowerCase);
```

At least, I hope this may satisfy your "help me understand JavaScript better" requirement. :-)